# Getting indices while using train test split in scikit

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

In order to split my data into train and test data separately, I'm using

`sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split` function.

When I supply my data and labels as list of lists to this function, it returns train and test data in two separate lists.

I want to get the indices of the train and test data elements from the original data list.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521170/scikit-learn-train-test-split-with-indices).

Answer (score 47):

You can  supply the index vector as an additional argument. Using the example from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X, y,indices = (0.1*np.arange(10)).reshape((5, 2)),range(10,15),range(5)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,indices_train,indices_test = train_test_split(X, y,indices, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
indices_train,indices_test
#([2, 0, 3], [1, 4])
```

Comment: Very simple and useful answer, bravo!

Comment: Great answer, much simpler and and more straightforward than many others.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solutions (depending on whether you have imbalance):

```py
NUM_ROWS = train.shape[0]
TEST_SIZE = 0.3
indices = np.arange(NUM_ROWS)

# usual train-val split
train_idx, val_idx = train_test_split(indices, test_size=TEST_SIZE, train_size=None)

# stratified train-val split as per Response's proportion (if imbalance)
strat_train_idx, strat_val_idx = train_test_split(indices, test_size=TEST_SIZE, stratify=y)
```