# How to generate 3 lists of random non-overlapping indices of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following bumpy array:

```
y = array([[0],
           [2],
           [0],
           [1],
           [0],
           [1],
           [1],
           [1],
           [0],
           [0],
           [2],
           [2],
           [1],
           [2]])
```

I want to generate 3 lists of non-overlapping indices of rows of `y` as follows:

```
list_1 = 70% of rows
list_2 = 15% of rows
list_3 = 15% of rows
```

I know how to generate a single list, e.g. `list_1`:

```
import numpy as np

list_1 = [np.random.choice(np.where(y == i)[0], size=n_1, replace=False) for i in np.unique(y)]
```

where `n_1` is equal to the number of rows that correspond to 70% of all rows. In the above example of `y` there are totally 14 rows. It means that 70% of 14 rows is equal to 9 (rounded down to 9). Therefore `n_1` would be equal to 9.

However, I don't know how to generate the rest of lists (`list_2` and `list_3`), so that they do not overlap with the row indices in `list_1`.

Comment: Maybe you could create three index arrays. Use set differences to form the next index arrays.

Comment: just shuffle the entire array and slice the shuffle output.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: It is indeed a good idea. Could you please show how can I do it?

Comment: [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: From the documentation of `shuffle`: "Note that even for small len(x), the total number of permutations of x can quickly grow larger than the period of most random number generators. This implies that most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated. For example, a sequence of length 2080 is the largest that can fit within the period of the Mersenne Twister random number generator."

Comment: You're asking how to **split a list/dataset into training/test/holdout sets**. There are [661 existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+split+training+test+is%3Aq): do you want numpy, base python, scikit-learn or pandas?

Comment: @smci: Thanks. It's useful. But I need to get indices as the result.

Comment: @ScalaBoy: you can easily get lists of indices by doing the partitioning on the indices, rather than the data. [numpy does 3-way split directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250710/how-to-split-data-into-3-sets-train-validation-and-test); that's an exact duplicate. Or you can do [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) (do it twice).

Comment: @smci: I already found the solution that uses `np.random.permutation(y.shape[0])` as a starting point. It returns indices as I need. `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` is not what I need as it does not return indices.

Comment: I don't see that you need indices, can you explain your reason for not directly splitting the data? But anyway, here's a duplicate with `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` [Getting indices while using train test split in scikit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622396/getting-indices-while-using-train-test-split-in-scikit?rq=1). That function only does 2-way splits, so you need to call it twice to get a 3-way split.

Comment: @smci: The reason is that I have X and y objects. The object X has a shape (1000, 20, 120) and the object y has a shape (1000,1). Therefore I use `y` to get the indices and then I use these indices to filter both X and y in order to get X_train, X_val, X_test, y_train, y_val, y_test.

Comment: But [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) will split X,y simultaneously (or indeed any arbitrary sequence of lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes you give it). So you shouldn't need to keep the indices. But you can also get them from the function call if you really want.

Answer (score -1):

you have **y** and **list1** now,

```
l2 = list(set(y) - set(list1))
```

Now from l2 you can run same code of np.random.choice and choose next 15%
and save it in list2, then perform

```
list3 = list(set(l2) - set(list2))
```

Comment: How to get `l3`? Like this? `l3 = y.symmetric_difference(np.concatenate(list1,l2))`

Comment: you can take symmetric_difference of list2 from l2, and the remaining element will be list 3

Comment: I don't understand. I do not have `list2`. I only have `list1` as a starting point. If I create `list2` in the same way as I created `list1` and then I apply `symmetric_difference`, then I will get a smaller number of rows in `list2` which will not correspond to 15%.

Comment: Sorry, in your update you use `list2`. As I said, I only have `list1` as a starting point. The reason is explained in the above comment. If I use your approach (if I understood it correctly), I will not get 75%/15%/15%. Can you please put the complete code starting from `list1` and show how it works on my data?